Dataflow streaming pipeline from pubsub to bigquery stalls (python beam sdk, streaming inserts)
I am trying to set up a streaming pipeline using the python beam sdk (2.54.0).
The pipeline works fine but is not scaling well when there is a important increase of input pubsub messages ( when pubsub traffic is increased or when streaming is paused and later resumed causing  messages accumulating in the backlog of the pubsub subscription).
What I mean by not scaling well:
The pipeline is blocked on warning messages (image and msg below) and starts auto-scaling by creating new workers that results in the same warning messages. The pipeline keeps running indefinetely. Any idea of what happened and how to improve the pipeline (code below) ?
Below is the pipeline code:
def run(pipeline_args, known_args):
    """Run the load of pubsub messages to Bigquery in streaming mode."""
    options = PipelineOptions(pipeline_args)
    options.view_as(SetupOptions).save_main_session = True
    options.view_as(StandardOptions).streaming = True
    options.view_as(GoogleCloudOptions).project = known_args.project_id

    bigquery_schema = {
        "fields": [
            {"name": "id", "type": "STRING"},
            {"name": "source_data", "type": "STRING"},
            {"name": "processing_time", "type": "TIMESTAMP"},
            {"name": "event_time", "type": "TIMESTAMP"},
            {"name": "change_id", "type": "STRING"},
            {"name": "operation_type", "type": "STRING"},
            {"name": "coll_name", "type": "STRING"},
        ]
    }

    with beam.Pipeline(options=options) as p:
        (
            p
            | "Read PubSub Messages" >> beam.io.ReadFromPubSub( subscription=f"projects/{known_args.project_id}/subscriptions/{known_args.input_subscription}", with_attributes=True )
            | "Transform to TableRow" >> beam.ParDo( lambda msg: generate_row(msg)) # some processing 
            | "WritetoBQ" >> beam.io.WriteToBigQuery(
                table=lambda element: f"{known_args.project_id}:warehouse.{element['coll_name']}_hist",
                schema=bigquery_schema,
                method=beam.io.WriteToBigQuery.Method.STREAMING_INSERTS,
                with_auto_sharding=True,
                triggering_frequency=int(known_args.triggering_period),
                write_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_APPEND,
                create_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED,
                additional_bq_parameters={
                    "timePartitioning": {"type": "DAY"},
                },
            )
        )


warning messages 1
Operation ongoing in bundle process_bundle-217-222 for PTransform{name=WritetoBQ/_StreamToBigQuery/StreamInsertRows/ParDo(BigQueryWriteFn)-ptransform-59, state=process-msecs} for at least 469.94 seconds without outputting or completing.
Current Traceback:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/threading.py", line 1002, in _bootstrap
    self._bootstrap_inner()

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/threading.py", line 1045, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/apache_beam/utils/thread_pool_executor.py", line 53, in run
    self._work_item.run()

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/apache_beam/utils/thread_pool_executor.py", line 37, in run
    self._future.set_result(self._fn(*self._fn_args, **self._fn_kwargs))

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/sdk_worker.py", line 385, in task
    self._execute(

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/sdk_worker.py", line 311, in _execute
    response = task()

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/sdk_worker.py", line 386, in <lambda>
    lambda: self.create_worker().do_instruction(request), request)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/sdk_worker.py", line 650, in do_instruction
    return getattr(self, request_type)(

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/sdk_worker.py", line 688, in process_bundle
    bundle_processor.process_bundle(instruction_id))

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/bundle_processor.py", line 1110, in process_bundle
    self.ops[element.transform_id].process_timer(

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/apache_beam/io/gcp/bigquery.py", line 1596, in process
    return self._flush_batch(destination)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/apache_beam/io/gcp/bigquery.py", line 1638, in _flush_batch
    passed, errors = self.bigquery_wrapper.insert_rows(

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/apache_beam/io/gcp/bigquery_tools.py", line 1273, in insert_rows
    result, errors = self._insert_all_rows(

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/apache_beam/utils/retry.py", line 298, in wrapper
    return fun(*args, **kwargs)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/apache_beam/io/gcp/bigquery_tools.py", line 724, in _insert_all_rows
    errors = self.gcp_bq_client.insert_rows_json(

  File "/opt/apache/beam-venv/beam-venv-worker-sdk-0-0/lib/python3.11/site-packages/google/cloud/bigquery/client.py", line 3799, in insert_rows_json
    response = self._call_api(

  File "/opt/apache/beam-venv/beam-venv-worker-sdk-0-0/lib/python3.11/site-packages/google/cloud/bigquery/client.py", line 831, in _call_api
    return call()

  File "/opt/apache/beam-venv/beam-venv-worker-sdk-0-0/lib/python3.11/site-packages/google/api_core/retry/retry_unary.py", line 293, in retry_wrapped_func
    return retry_target(

  File "/opt/apache/beam-venv/beam-venv-worker-sdk-0-0/lib/python3.11/site-packages/google/api_core/retry/retry_unary.py", line 164, in retry_target
    time.sleep(sleep)

warning messages 2
{
insertId: "9072863453752207109:172469:0:83958"
jsonPayload: {
instruction: "process_bundle-218-223"
job: "2024-04-26_04_45_37-3110838924942014298"
logger: "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/apache_beam/utils/histogram.py:77"
message: "record is out of upper bound 60000: 566992"
portability_worker_id: "sdk-0-0_sibling_1"
step: "WritetoBQ/_StreamToBigQuery/StreamInsertRows/ParDo(BigQueryWriteFn)"
thread: "Thread-23"
work: "218"
worker: "stream-2024-04-26--13-45--04260448-j4jl-harness-gsbw"
}
...

warning messages 3
Retry with exponential backoff: waiting for 3.087997091292767 seconds before retrying _insert_all_rows because we caught exception: google.api_core.exceptions.RetryError: Timeout of 600.0s exceeded, last exception: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='bigquery.googleapis.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /bigquery/v2/projects/XXX/datasets/XXX/tables/XXX/insertAll?prettyPrint=false (Caused by SSLError(SSLEOFError(8, 'EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:2427)')))
 Traceback for above exception (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/apache_beam/utils/retry.py", line 298, in wrapper
    return fun(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/apache_beam/io/gcp/bigquery_tools.py", line 724, in _insert_all_rows
    errors = self.gcp_bq_client.insert_rows_json(
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/apache/beam-venv/beam-venv-worker-sdk-0-0/lib/python3.11/site-packages/google/cloud/bigquery/client.py", line 3799, in insert_rows_json
    response = self._call_api(
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/apache/beam-venv/beam-venv-worker-sdk-0-0/lib/python3.11/site-packages/google/cloud/bigquery/client.py", line 831, in _call_api
    return call()
           ^^^^^^
  File "/opt/apache/beam-venv/beam-venv-worker-sdk-0-0/lib/python3.11/site-packages/google/api_core/retry/retry_unary.py", line 293, in retry_wrapped_func
    return retry_target(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/apache/beam-venv/beam-venv-worker-sdk-0-0/lib/python3.11/site-packages/google/api_core/retry/retry_unary.py", line 153, in retry_target
    _retry_error_helper(
  File "/opt/apache/beam-venv/beam-venv-worker-sdk-0-0/lib/python3.11/site-packages/google/api_core/retry/retry_base.py", line 221, in _retry_error_helper
    raise final_exc from source_exc

Also:
Before scaling, the pipeline worked well with a triggering_period from 60 to 3600 s.
By scaling (more pubsub traffic), the pipeline always stalls when triggering_period is above 360s.

You can ignore warnings or errors as long as these are retriable. From https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/write-to-bigquery, have you tried STORAGE_WRITE_API or STORAGE_API_AT_LEAST_ONCE?

Have't tried it yet. Saw that it was the recommended method. Do you know any drawbacks in switching from STREAMING_INSERTS to STORAGE_WRITE_API/STORAGE_API_AT_LEAST_ONCE ?

check https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/write-to-bigquery#best-practices-general. You should pay attentions to the quota.
